Deeplearning4j - creating a model for strings employee, worker, associate etc
I wanted to build a model / train the model using deeplearning4j.
This model should understand all the employee related jargon for example, it should understand the words Employee, Worker, Associate as same words.
I was using below code snippet to create Data Set and have the iterator
    DataSet allData;
    try (RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(0, ',')) {
        recordReader.initialize(new StringSplit("Employee ID,0"));

        DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, 150, FEATURES_COUNT, CLASSES_COUNT);
        allData = iterator.next();
    }

    allData.shuffle(42);

and ending up with following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Employee ID"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    at org.datavec.api.writable.Text.toDouble(Text.java:590)
    at org.datavec.api.util.ndarray.RecordConverter.toMinibatchArray(RecordConverter.java:207)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:153)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:346)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:421)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:53)
    at com.test.dl4jtest.dl4jtest.TrainModel.main(TrainModel.java:46)

Please suggest how do i create a model that should consider terms like worker, asociate, employee as an employee here.

I recommend you looking at the data pipeline examples on the deeplearning4j examples page, especially CSVMixedDataTypesLocal.java in your case.
